# Webpack: emitted chunks do not create a main entrypoint

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks

I upgraded webpack from version 2 to version 4. My config includes:

```
entry = {
    Main: './main',
    App: './app'
};
```

and

```
var output = {
    path: path.join(__dirname, outPath, '_js'),
    publicPath: '/_js/',
    filename: '[name]-bundle.js'
};
```

In version 2, my output was simply `App-bundle.js` and `Main-bundle.js`, but in webpack@4 the output is

```
Entrypoints:
  Main (414 KiB)
      Main~493df0b3-bundle.js
      Main~4c0201b9-bundle.js
  App (316 KiB)
      App~47dad47d-bundle.js
      App~6bd0612f-bundle.js
      App~01e7b97c-bundle.js
```

without a central, non-hashed file name to import.

**EDIT:**

My `optimization` object looks like this:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'async',
        minSize: 20000,
        maxSize: env === 'production' ? 1000000 : 0,
        minChunks: 1,
        maxAsyncRequests: 6,
        maxInitialRequests: 4,
        automaticNameDelimiter: '~',
        cacheGroups: {
          default: {
            minChunks: 1,
            priority: -20,
            reuseExistingChunk: true
          }
        }
    },
    minimize: env === 'production' ? true : false
},
```

**--- QUESTION ---**

I'm ok having chunks, but how do I configure webpack 4 in order to have a central entry file called simply `Main-bundle.js` and `App-bundle.js` that I can easily import in my HTML templates?

Comment: It looks like you have cache groups enabled, are you using splitChunks?

Comment: Did you configure `optimization` configuration in webpack configuruation? maybe `moduleIds: hashed`? Can you post your whole webpack config please?

Comment: try adding `.js` suffix for your entry points: ```entry = {
    Main: './main.js',
    App: './app.js'
};```

Comment: @RazRonen yes, I am using SplitChunks. But the version 2 also had `CommonsChunkPlugin`.

Comment: @RazRonen I have added my `optimization` block.

Comment: I made my entry points `./main.js` etc. No change in the output sadly.

Comment: Theres no question that this issue comes from splitChunks configurations.

Comment: Try deleting min max size to see if this is the issue please

Comment: Deleting min/max size seems to have done the trick. Which leads me to a question - what is the point of having this option? How could I have used the files in the "chunked" format? BTW feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I'll add a reference for this in the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please delete `minSize` and `maxSize` in your `splitChunks` configurations.
Or alternatively, lower the minSize and uprise maxSize.

`minSize` and `maxSize` are quite handy when you want to fine-tune your chunks for performance, or other reasons that consider chunk size.

Personally I found out that having 600KB size chunks for 10 chunks that are downloaded as 'inital chunks' are the best fine-tune performance in my application. I couldn't reach the same perf results without it, as webpack created an uneven and big chunks for some of my entry points.

Comment: Somehow, deleting `minSize` and `maxSize` ensured that a single file is created, thus solving my problem. While I would have liked to find a way to use the chunked version of the resulting file, this answer ultimately solves my problem.

Comment: Usually filename configuration are configured by `output: {
     filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
},` which signs the chunk with the contenthash. Still just one output file like you want, but with a hash. This will save you problems in the future when you release a new version of your assets. Otherwise users will still get the old one from their cache.

Comment: So what should I have done? Manually included all the chunks in my HTML template?

Comment: You can use [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/) to do that for you